# how do I check balance of USDT(Tether) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptocurrency, wallet

I was working on my python crypto project recently, but I had to make a method that checks balance of Tether wallet. Is there a way to check balance of tether with python?
this is my code:

```
class wallet_Tether:
#Tether shares same blockchain with bitcoin

def __init__(self,wallet_address,wallet_privatekey,wallet_balance,wallet_history,wallet_public_key,wallet_name,wallet):

    self.wallet_address = wallet_address
    self.wallet_privatekey = wallet_privatekey
    self.wallet_balance = wallet_balance
    self.wallet_history = wallet_history
    self.wallet_public_key = wallet_public_key
    self.wallet_name = wallet_name
    self.wallet = wallet

def create_address(self):

    self.wallet = Wallet.create(self.wallet_name)
    key_usdt = self.wallet.get_key()
    self.wallet_address = key_usdt.get_address

    return self.wallet_address

def check_balance(self):

    return self.wallet_balance
```

Comment: not so related to your question, but you could add ```*args```  to your `__init__` to reduce the number of parameters, and just initialise them in the body.

Comment: It is prototype yet, so I will do it later

Answer (score 2):

**You can use tether explorer api to get balance information.**

For example, etherscan.io api ->

It allows you to send 100,000 requests per day and 5 requests per second for free.

https://docs.etherscan.io/getting-started/creating-an-account -> Some api docs

```
import requests

url = "https://api.etherscan.io/api"
address = "Your address"
apikey = "Your apikey"
params = {"module": "account", "action": "balance", "address": address, "tag": "latest", "apikey": apikey}
response = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
```

Variable **response** contains a dictionary with balance data.
Example:

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "message":"OK",
   "result":"40891626854930000000000" 
}
```

The result is returned in wei. So, we need to divide **result** by 10^18

```
total_balance = int(response["result"]) / (10**18)
```

Where total_balance - your tether wallet balance

Comment: so how do I get USDT not ethereum I know how to get ethereum already